# Unity-iOS: The default Firebase app has not yet been configured

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I've imported Admob and firebase into my unity project. also, downloaded .plist file from firebase website. the main issue is after "Build and Run", i see this error in the xcode log:

[Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more ...

I've done all of it from instructions step by step.

i need help, any idea?

Comment: Show your app delegate file

Comment: Excuse me that i ask this question. where is this file?! i can't find it when i compile game with unity...

Comment: it is called AppDelegate.swift, maybe you can do a search in your files. I do not code with unity but I think that file should exist

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot find this in the project, i update all things in my mac. unity 2017.1, and all new packages... AppDelegate.swift is not there...

Comment: Can you just search on your Mac for AppDelegate? I can not believe you do not have that file...

Comment: When i create new Xcode project, AppDelegate.swift is in project, but when i export with unity, its not there...